# Checking for unsigned long long overflow

Tags: c, overflow, long-integer, unsigned, addition

I am trying to generate fibonacci numbers and I am storing them as unsigned long longs. However i wish to stop generating more numbers if the new number in the series is larger than what a unsigned long long can hold. I currently have the following.

```
unsigned long long n1 = 1, n2 = 1, n3;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(i == 0 || i == 1) {
            fprintf(fibonacci_file, "%lld\n", n1);
        }else {
            n3 = n1 + n2;
            if(n3 < n1) {
                printf("FIBONACCI OVERFLOW\n");
                break;
            }else {
                fprintf(fibonacci_file, "%lld\n", n3);
                n1 = n2;
                n2 = n3;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then end of the output file looks like this.

```
1100087778366101931
1779979416004714189
2880067194370816120
4660046610375530309
7540113804746346429
-6246583658587674878
```

The last one is negative, meaning the result overflowed. However my check should have caught it and not printed it out, and ended the loop.

Comment: Change `%lld` to `%llu`. Calculation is fine, it's just the print format that is wrong.

Comment: Even better would be `if (ULLONG_MAX - n2 < n1)` before doing the sum `n3 = n1 + n2`, to prevent overflow in the first place.

Comment: Note that signed integer overflow is undefined behaviour and has to be avoided. As is converting an unsigned integer to a signed integer which cannot hold the value. Unsigned integer overflow otoh is well-defined, but you should be very carefull not to have a signed integer in the chain.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! Spent so long trying to fix it thinking my logic was wrong. Didn't even consider it was just the formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Wrong specifier used to print the full range of `unsigned long long`.  Use `"%llu"`. [@void_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33223864/checking-for-unsigned-long-long-overflow/33224400#comment54252456_33223864)

```
unsigned long long n3;
....
// fprintf(fibonacci_file, "%lld\n", n3);
fprintf(fibonacci_file, "%llu\n", n3);
```

---

OP's method of detecting overflow is fine as in C, mathematical overflow is well defined to simply "wrap".  That is pseudo-code: `unsigned_sum = math_sum mod (UMAX+1)` given the max of the type involved.

```
 if (n3 < n1) {
   printf("FIBONACCI OVERFLOW\n");
   break;
```

A deleted discussion also proposed an idiomatic test  [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33223864/checking-for-unsigned-long-long-overflow/33224400#comment54252578_33223864) and [@Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4774918/olaf) which would also work.  This approach is useful when the type involved is not unsigned integers, but signed integers or floating point.

```
 if (ULLONG_MAX - n2 < n1) {
   printf("FIBONACCI OVERFLOW\n");
   break;
 }
 n3 = n1 + n2;
```

---

Further, the series is sometimes considered to start at `F[0] = 0`.  See [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)